# how to use progress bar on lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I put this slds progress bar code in my lightning component

```
<aura:component  controller="myController" >
<div>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread slds-p-bottom_x-small" id="progress-bar-label-id-1">
     <span>Status</span>
     <span aria-hidden="true">
        <strong>25% Complete</strong>
     </span>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-progress-bar barStyle" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="25" aria-labelledby="progress-bar-label-id-1" role="progressbar">
    <span class="slds-progress-bar__value" style="width: 25%;">
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Progress: 25%</span>
    </span>
    </div>
```

It's just part of the whole code. I'm already using a controller for this component. I just need to add a progress bar on one of the rows. I have another controller for the progress bar that computes from apex jobs. I just dont know how to apply it on this lightning component. I'm still confused. 
i've found a sample code on net that I wish to apply...but i dont know how to start it...

this is the sample code that I might want to apply found in this [site](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Sunil02kumar/20110df3e053ca6b86c7d6320a07af4c/raw/11459da6875425bf3c0df4119a86af32b359eb85/Apex%20Class-BatchJobProgressBarController%20) but it's used on a visualforce page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a very specific requirement in terms of style, use the [lightning:progressBar base lightning component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:progressBar/example):

```
<lightning:progressBar value="50" size="large" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using the below

```
<lightning:progressIndicator currentStep="{!v.currentStepIs}" type="base">
         <lightning:progressStep label="1st Step" value="" onclick=""/>
         <lightning:progressStep label="2nd Step" value="" onclick=""/>
         <lightning:progressStep label="3rd Step" value="" onclick=""/>
    </lightning:progressIndicator>
```

Comment: what you are proposing here is a progress indicator and not a progress bar. It's a different component from what OP requested.